# What makes meadows bloom in Loop Hero?

Tags: loop-hero

Sometimes when I place meadows they bloom, the sprite changes to show flowers, and the bonus HP per day steps up from 2 to 3.  Other times the meadows just stay flat and provide the standard 2 HP per day only.

I at first thought that simply placing the meadows beside other tiles made this happen but it doesn't seem consistent so I think there must be more to it.

How do I get meadows to buff consistently?

[image: Meadows]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meadows bloom when they are next to another non-meadow tile. It can be anything, either rocks/mountains or buildings that you have placed or are placed automatically.